# LWJGL 3.1.6 crashes on Win 10

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, vbo, vao

even if this question was ask multiple times (i readed all of that and no solution worked for me), I am trying to model a rectangle with LWJGL and OpenGL
, but it crashes every time. Here my PC-Stats:

AMD-Ryzen 1600x  | 
MSI Nvidia GTX 1060 (6GB)  | 
MSI x370 Carbon Pro Motherboard

I also tried this on an Intel-Setup, with an i7 Processor and a Nvidia Quadro K 1000M setup, but same Error you can see in the following:

https://hastebin.com/ayiqiritov.makefile

My Drawing Method:

```
public void render(RawModel model){
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(model.getVaoID());
    GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    GL11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, model.getVertexCount());
    GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

In this class I create VAOs and the VBOs and store data into those:

```
    private List<Integer> vaos = new ArrayList<Integer>();
private List<Integer> vbos = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public RawModel loadToVAO(float[] positions) {
    int vaoID = createVAO();
    storeDataInAttributeList(0, positions);
    unbindVAO();
    return new RawModel(vaoID, positions.length / 3);
}

public void cleanUp() {
    for (int vao : vaos) {
        GL30.glDeleteVertexArrays(vao);
    }
    for (int vbo : vbos) {
        GL15.glDeleteBuffers(vbo);
    }
}

private int createVAO() {
    int vaoID = GL30.glGenVertexArrays();
    vaos.add(vaoID);
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(vaoID);
    return vaoID;
}

private void storeDataInAttributeList(int attributeNumber, float[] data) {
    int vboID = GL15.glGenBuffers();
    vbos.add(vboID);
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
    FloatBuffer buffer = storeDataInFloatBuffer(data);
    GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(attributeNumber, 3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}

private void unbindVAO() {
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
}

private FloatBuffer storeDataInFloatBuffer(float[] data) {
    FloatBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(data.length);
    buffer.put(data).position(0);
    buffer.flip();
    return buffer;
}
```

And my main Method:

```
        public static void main(String[] args){
    if(!glfwInit()){
        throw new IllegalStateException("Failed");
    }

    System.out.println(GL11.glGetString(GL11.GL_VERSION));

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GLFW_FALSE);

    GLFW.glfwWindowHint(GLFW.GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    GLFW.glfwWindowHint(GLFW.GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);

    long window = GLFW.glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", 0, 0);

    if(window == 0){
        throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to create Window");
    }

    GLFWVidMode vidmode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
    glfwSetWindowPos(window, (vidmode.width() - 640) / 2, (vidmode.height() - 480) / 2);

    glfwShowWindow(window);

    Loader loader = new Loader();
    Renderer renderer = new Renderer();

    float[] vertices = {
        -0.5f, 0.5f, 0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0f,

        0.5f, -0.5f, 0f,
        0.5f, 0.5f, 0f,
        -0.5f, 0.5f, 0f
    };

    RawModel model = loader.loadToVAO(vertices);

    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){
        renderer.prepare();
        renderer.render(model);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    loader.cleanUp();
    GLFW.glfwTerminate();

}
```

So I have already tried:

Update drivers for Graphic-card, update java, update Windows, setting up a new eclipse, reinstall java and deleting .metadata in eclipse.

Can anyone pls help me?

Comment: Where is the shader program?

Comment: I dont have implemented a shader yet... Or what do you mean?

Comment: Seems a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37377150/3871028). Start with Rabbid76 answer (set OGL >=3.0) an continue with next errors you will meet.

Comment: Ok now I have a red screen, but nothing renders on it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comment

> I dont have implemented a shader yet

The state of the art way of rendering in OpenGL, would be to use a [Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader).

If you don't use a shader, than you have to define the array of vertex data by [`glVertexPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glVertexPointer.xml). `glVertexPointer` specifies a array for Fixed-Function vertex coordinate attribute. If you don't have a shader program, then you have to use the [Fixed Function Pipeline](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fixed_Function_Pipeline).

```
private void storeDataInAttributeList(int attributeNumber, float[] data) {
    int vboID = GL15.glGenBuffers();
    vbos.add(vboID);
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
    FloatBuffer buffer = storeDataInFloatBuffer(data);
    GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    GL11.glVertexPointer( 3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0 ); // <---------

    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

Further you have to enable the client-side capability for vertex coordinates by [`glEnableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY )`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glEnableClientState.xml):

```
public void render(RawModel model){
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(model.getVaoID());

    GL11.glEnableClientState( GL11.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );   // <---------

    GL11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, model.getVertexCount());

    GL11.glDisableClientState( GL11.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );  // <---------

    GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

---

Further note, that you have to creates the "GLCapabilities" instance and makes the OpenGL bindings available for use before you use an OpenGL instruction like `GL30.glGenVertexArrays()` and you have to ensure the the OpenGL context is current.

Call [`glfwMakeContextCurrent(window)`](https://javadoc.lwjgl.org/org/lwjgl/glfw/GLFW.html#glfwMakeContextCurrent(long)) and [`GL.createCapabilities()`](https://javadoc.lwjgl.org/org/lwjgl/opengl/GL.html#createCapabilities()) after creating the window and before any OpenGL instruction:

```
long window = GLFW.glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", 0, 0);
if(window == 0){
    throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to create Window");
}

GLFWVidMode vidmode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
glfwSetWindowPos(window, (vidmode.width() - 640) / 2, (vidmode.height() - 480) / 2);

glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);  // <-----

glfwShowWindow(window);

GL.createCapabilities();         // <-----

.....
```

---

Finally you are missing [`glfwSwapBuffers`](https://javadoc.lwjgl.org/org/lwjgl/glfw/GLFW.html#glfwSwapBuffers(long)) int the render loop. `glfwSwapBuffers` Swaps the front and back buffers of the specified window. In other, simple words it binges the buffer where you rendered to, onto the screen:

```
while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){
    renderer.prepare();
    renderer.render(model);

    glfwSwapBuffers(window); // <-----

    glfwPollEvents();
}
```

---

See also [LWJGL 3 Guide - Getting Started](https://www.lwjgl.org/guide)

Comment: Ok now I have a red screen, but nothing renders on it :(